# ASP.NET Refreshing UpdatePanel OnClientClick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a couple of update panels, one containing a gridview and another containing a detailsview. I have not been able to get a button in the detailsview to be able to trigger an update of the gridview update panel. I have tried several things (doing it from c# would be ok too..) however here is what I have now... any suggestions? [...I need "confirmButton" to trigger update in "SelectCarUP"]

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SelectCarUP" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="VehiclesGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="VehiclesEDS" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="VehiclesGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="GVSelectButton" runat="server" 
                     CausesValidation="False" 
                     CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="CarNum" HeaderText="Car" ReadOnly="True" 
               SortExpression="CarNum" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrPassengers" HeaderText="Passengers" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CurrPassengers" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MaxPassengers" HeaderText="Capacity"  
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MaxPassengers" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Status" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="StartAdd" HeaderText="Pick-Up Address" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StartAdd" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="EndAdd" HeaderText="Drop-Off Address" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EndAdd" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="AvgRideTime" HeaderText="Avg. Ride Time" 
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AvgRideTime" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#004812" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" 
           HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C6940D" Font-Bold="True" 
           ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C6940D" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#9F770B" />
     </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CssClass="DefaultTable">
   <asp:TableRow runat="server">
       <asp:TableCell runat="server" Width="50%" 
           VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Left">
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="detailsUP" runat="server" 
                UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <!--
                     <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" 
                        Text="Car To Dispatch: " CssClass="DefaultLabel">
                     </asp:Label>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="CarsDDL" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="VehiclesEDS" 
                        DataMember="CarNum" DataTextField="CarNum"
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" Font-Bold="True">
                           <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="-">
                           </asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                  -->
                  <asp:DetailsView ID="RideToAssignDV" runat="server"
                      Height="400px" Width="400px" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                      BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
                      BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                      CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True"
                           ForeColor="White" />
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AssignedCar" 
                                HeaderText="Car"             
                                SortExpression="AssignedCar" NullDisplayText="---" />            
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
                                SortExpression="Name" NullDisplayText="---" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" 
                                SortExpression="Phone" NullDisplayText="---" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NumPatrons" HeaderText="Size" 
                                SortExpression="NumPatrons" NullDisplayText="---" />                
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PickupAddress" 
                                HeaderText="Pickup Address" 
                                SortExpression="PickupAddress" NullDisplayText="---" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DropoffAddress" 
                                HeaderText="Drop-Off Address" 
                                SortExpression="DropoffAddress" 
                                NullDisplayText="---" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" 
                                HeaderText="Created By" 
                                SortExpression="CreatedBy" NullDisplayText="---" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeOfCall" 
                                HeaderText="Call Time" 
                                SortExpression="TimeOfCall" ReadOnly="True"
                                NullDisplayText="---" />
                        </Fields>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black"
                            BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="#C6940D"
                            HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="25px" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server"
                                Text="Confirm" ForeColor="Green" 
                                HorizontalAlign="Center" OnClick="confirmButton_Click"
                                OnClientClick="refreshGV();"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel"
                                ForeColor="Red" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                OnClick="cancelButton_Click"
                                OnClientClick="displayTopTen();" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#004812" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />                            
                 </asp:DetailsView>
          </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:TableCell>

<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshGV() {
             __doPostBack("<%= SelectCarUP.ClientID %>", "");
         }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this.confirmButton);
```

Refer [this ASP.net forum](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2008/04/26/refresh-the-updatepanel-using-javascript-code.aspx)

**OR**

On your button click event handler inside codebehind call `SelectCarUP.Update()` It should update the `SelectCarUP` panel. For more info refer [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb386454.aspx).

**OR**

In code behind you can add trigger for this button (not sure about this)

```
SelectCarUP.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = confirmButton.UniqueID,
    EventName = "Click"
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: hmm, these are all very good suggestions, and I had already tried 2 of them, the problem is...I get an error that "confirmButton" doesnt exist..I think because it is nested within the DetailsView.. any thoughts??

Comment: Where do you get this error, in code behind or in javascript?

Comment: What about option 2? Can you nest the update panels? I have given you one MSDN article, it has some mechanism for nested update panel.

Comment: It allows the syntax but doesn't seem to update the data being displayed, is there something beyond just an update that I need to do to make it query the database again for current info? (The gridview im trying to update is using an EntityDataSource that is attached to an sql db)

Comment: Did you bind the data again and then call `Update`? If this doesn't work nest the update panel or wrap all the code in single update panel.

Comment: Excellent, calling databind again first did the trick. Thanks!